# Auto hide feature for collapsable pane

Tags: javafx, hide

I want to integrate auto-hide logic to my collapsable pane. Do you know how to do that in JavaFX? Any small example will work for me. I can integrate into my code.

I know the controlFX code but it will be hard to integrate that code in my existing code.

So if you know any small standalone example please share it with me.

Kind Regards,

Comment: When it should auto hide?

Comment: It will auto hide anything which I want, right? In my case it will auto hide VBox.

Comment: I am not saying about the content of the pane, I want to know how and when the pane should auto hide. So basically you want an Accordion that auto hides but when?

Comment: In my application left hand side is a search area. When mouse/cursor moved out from that area it will auto hide. And on top of it, I would like to add one pin over there if it pushed/clicked then sidebar will not auto hide. Something like if you share your screen via Microsoft Lync.